# OpenCV with Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: opencv, blazor, blazor-client-side

I'd like to build a web app with Blazor WebAssembly and do some image processing on the client side with OpenCV. I'm having difficulty using OpenCV on the client side. There are two approaches I've tried:

1. Include the OpenCVSharp4 NuGet package in the Client project. However, as the OpenCVSharp is just a wrapper, I suppose that requires a runtime dll to do the actual work. I tired to add the OpenCVSharp4.runtime.win package and the code using OpenCV generates the error `WASM: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OpenCvSharp.NativeMethods' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: OpenCvSharpExtern assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)` saying it can't find the dll.
2. Use OpenCV.js with WebAssembly. I've tried just adding `<script src="opencv.js" async></script>` in index.html, but the app fail to load with the following error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at Module.stackSave (dotnet.js:1)
    at ccall (dotnet.js:1)
    at Object.wasm_setenv (dotnet.js:1)
    at Object.mono_wasm_setenv (dotnet.js:1)
    at blazor.webassembly.js:1
    at callRuntimeCallbacks (opencv.js:30)
    at postRun (opencv.js:30)
    at doRun (opencv.js:30)
    at run (opencv.js:30)
    at runCaller (opencv.js:30)
```

So is it feasible to use OpenCV on the client side with Blazor? If so, how to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Approach 1 will not work.

Comment: Approach 2 might be feasible. Look in your F12/Network panel and check if  ther are any 404 errors.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks! I'll look more into that.

Comment: It seems currently "Blazor WebAssembly" has some issue with  OpenCV. Try Blazor Server.

Comment: @R-penguins I was just wondering if you had some success with this?  I'm also going the route of OpenCV.js but am having some issues.

Comment: OpenCVSharp4 now (2023) works well with Blazor WebAssembly via the runtime package OpenCvSharp4.runtime.wasm. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but it is worth answering. OpenCVSharp4 is currently working well with Blazor WASM.

[My OpenCVSharp4 Blazor WASM demo](https://lostbeard.github.io/SpawnDev.BlazorJS.OpenCVSharp4/) showing basic Canny edge detection on an image and Haar Cascade face and eye detection with a webcam and video. The live demo repo [SpawnDev.BlazorJS.OpenCVSharp4](https://github.com/LostBeard/SpawnDev.BlazorJS.OpenCVSharp4) on GitHub.

The demo uses [OpenCVSharp4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp4) and [OpenCvSharp4.runtime.wasm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp4.runtime.wasm/) Nuget packages by [Shimat](https://github.com/shimat)

Shimat's [OpenCvSharp4 repo](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp)

Comment: Thank you very much for this demo! But how is this working for you? I cloned your repo but I get the same error message (The type initializer for 'OpenCvSharp.Internal.NativeMethods' threw an exception / System.DllNotFoundException) when I run it locally. Any Ideas what might be missing?