# Is OpenCV with Blazor WASM in .NET6 feasible?

Tags: opencv, blazor, webassembly

I'd like to process images on clientside with Blazor WASM and OpenCV. I can run OpenCV with the OpenCVSharp4 NuGet Package serverside, but that wont cut it. If I try to let it run on the Client I get:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OpenCvSharp.Internal.NativeMethods' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: OpenCvSharpExtern

Another try I gave it was to use the opencv.js, but if I try to load it with
`<script src="opencv.js" async></script>` but it fails with

> Error: Failed to start platform. Reason: TypeError: Module._malloc is not a function
> at St (blazor.webassembly.js:1)

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
> at Module.stackSave (_framework/dotnet.6.0.0.tj42mwroj7.js:1)
> at ccall (_framework/dotnet.6.0.0.tj42mwroj7.js:1)
> at Object.wasm_setenv (_framework/dotnet.6.0.0.tj42mwroj7.js:1)
> at Object.mono_wasm_setenv (_framework/dotnet.6.0.0.tj42mwroj7.js:1)
> at blazor.webassembly.js:1
> at callRuntimeCallbacks (opencv.js:30)
> at postRun (opencv.js:30)
> at doRun (opencv.js:30)
> at run (opencv.js:30)
> at runCaller (opencv.js:30)

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
> at Object.Module._malloc (_framework/dotnet.6.0.0.tj42mwroj7.js:1)
> at Object.mono_wasm_load_bytes_into_heap (_framework/dotnet.6.0.0.tj42mwroj7.js:1)
> at blazor.webassembly.js:1

I thought about the use of Native Dependencies with the .NET6 but I cant get it to work either. Is there anything essential I am missing?

Comment: This video could give you some pointers https://youtu.be/kesUNeBZ1Os

Comment: I saw that video, I tried the exact same thing, using the opencv.js but I get an error: 'unkown file type'
edit: I tried to precompile it and add the .wasm file, but now I get: 'opencv_js.wasm: not a relocatable wasm file'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [opencv-3.4.7.js](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.7/opencv.js) higher versions didn't work for me. And also load the opencv.js file before loading blazor wasm.

```js
<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <script src="/lib/opencv-3.4.7.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
    <script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenCVSharp4 is currently working well with Blazor WASM using OpenCvSharp4.runtime.wasm. ([Similar question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924258/opencv-with-blazor-webassembly/77205444#77205444))

[My OpenCVSharp4 Blazor WASM demo](https://lostbeard.github.io/SpawnDev.BlazorJS.OpenCVSharp4/) showing basic Canny edge detection on an image and Haar Cascade face and eye detection with a webcam and video. The live demo repo [SpawnDev.BlazorJS.OpenCVSharp4](https://github.com/LostBeard/SpawnDev.BlazorJS.OpenCVSharp4) on GitHub.

The demo uses [OpenCVSharp4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp4) and [OpenCvSharp4.runtime.wasm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp4.runtime.wasm/) Nuget packages by [Shimat](https://github.com/shimat)

Shimat's [OpenCvSharp4 repo](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is feasible
Refer below Proj file

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <WasmBuildNative>true</WasmBuildNative>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <RunAOTCompilation>True</RunAOTCompilation>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <RunAOTCompilation>True</RunAOTCompilation>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenCvSharp4" Version="4.5.5.20211231" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenCvSharp4.runtime.wasm" Version="4.5.5.20211231" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Check out the [Sample code](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp_blazor_sample/blob/main/BlazorApp/)

Comment: Hi, do you know if the OpenCV VideoCaputre APIs work on that github example? (I tried to use it but get a generic error always: 'Uncaught (in promise) 63723896'), thanks!